# Where does the snap package version of LXD store containers?

Tags: lxd

In [this tutorial](https://bayton.org/docs/linux/lxd/mount-cifssmb-shares-rw-in-lxd-containers/), the author gives the following location of the root directory in a container named `c1`:

```
/var/lib/lxd/containers/c1/rootfs/
```

What is the equivalent directory if I've installed lxd using `snap install lxd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04, lxd version 3.13, using the `dir` backend, it was this:

```
/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/c1/rootfs/
```